# Offsets in a Firebase node.js https get request loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise

The API I am working with sends data in blocks of 50 results maximum. To retrieve the next block I need to include an *offset* parameter eg. **offset="50"**.

Please help me amend my code to include a loop that will continue if the number of results in each loop = 50.

Thank you in advance.

```
 exports.offsetloop = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {

    var offset = "0";
    var from = "2017-03-01";
    var to = "2017-05-05";

    var http = require("https");
    var options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "hostname": "example.com",
        "port": null,
        "path": "/api/v1/entries.json?to="+to+"%2B00%253A00%253A00&from="+from+"%2B00%253A00%253A00&offset="+offset+"&api_key=123456",
        "headers": {
            "accept": "application/json"
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        var chunks = [];

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();

            body = JSON.parse(body);
            //save to database etc.
            //if(body.length == 50) loop using offset = 50

            res.end();
            });

        });  
    }
 req.end();
```

});

Comment: what is `result` in `result.end` ... does this code work at all, it shouldn't, because you call `req.end` when `req` is **not in scope**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following, recursively call the `getStuff` function, which contains most of your code:

```
var from = "2017-03-01";
var to = "2017-05-05";

var http = require("https");
function getStuff(offset) {
    var options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "hostname": "example.com",
        "port": null,
        "path": "/api/v1/entries.json?to=" + to + "%2B00%253A00%253A00&from=" + from + "%2B00%253A00%253A00&offset=" + offset + "&api_key=123456",
        "headers": {
            "accept": "application/json"
        }
    };
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        var chunks = [];
        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        res.on("end", function() {
            var body = Buffer.concat( chunks ).toString();
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            //save to database etc.
            if (body.length == 50) {
                getStuff(offset + 50);
            } else {
                // all done - do whatever cleanup needs to be done here
            }
        });
    });
}
getStuff(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I have tried your suggestion above and the script does not end, timing out after 60 seconds. I am trying to run it as a Firebase function. Any further help is appreciated.
Also I think I am confusing the res and req variables...

Comment: `timing out after 60 seconds` well, that seems like a network issue, or perhaps you didn't "do whatever cleanup needs to be done here" - I removed `res.end()` and `req.end()` from your original code, as it's not clear when they should be run in your code